# c# to compile an integer represented as binary

Tags: c#, binary

Is it possible to have the following:

```
var i = 000101;
```

To be compiled as:

```
var i = 5;
```

With some special character/token? Something like..

```
var i = B000101;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is... very abstract.  What do you want to do?

Comment: You can use `Convert.ToInt32("000101", 2)`, but this will obviously compile as a method call to be executed at runtime and not as a literal, constant value.